# Can I count the number of properties of an object if this object is a property of parent object in the property of this parent object when creating

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the number of properties of the FORMAT_LST object in the FORMAT_LST_COUNT property when creating the UTILS object

```
var UTILS = {
    FORMAT_LST: {
        'FORMAT1': 'format1',
        'FORMAT2': 'format2',
        'FORMAT3': 'format3'
    },
    FORMAT_LST_COUNT: Object.keys(this.FORMAT_LST).length
}
```

but it causes the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be a function

```js
var UTILS = {
  FORMAT_LST: {
    'FORMAT1': 'format1',
    'FORMAT2': 'format2',
    'FORMAT3': 'format3'
  },
  FORMAT_LST_COUNT: function() {
    return Object.keys(this.FORMAT_LST).length
  }
}
console.log(UTILS);
console.log(UTILS.FORMAT_LST_COUNT());
```

If it needs to be a property:

```js
var UTILS = new function() {
  this.FORMAT_LST = {
    'FORMAT1': 'format1',
    'FORMAT2': 'format2',
    'FORMAT3': 'format3'
  };
  this.FORMAT_LST_COUNT = Object.keys(this.FORMAT_LST).length
}
console.log(UTILS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrapping your code in the function block and returning it will do. Because else, the object does not know the statement and interprets it as another usual value.

```js
var UTILS = {
  FORMAT_LST: {
    'FORMAT1': 'format1',
    'FORMAT2': 'format2',
    'FORMAT3': 'format3'
  },
  FORMAT_LST_COUNT: function() { // function block
    return Object.keys(this.FORMAT_LST).length // return it
  }
}

console.log(UTILS.FORMAT_LST_COUNT()) // execute it
```

Answer (score 1):

Going totally overboard with complexity, this can be achieved by using the `defineProperties` method and defining `get FORMAT_LST_COUNT` as the length of keys.

```js
var UTILS = Object.defineProperties({}, {
  FORMAT_LST: {
    value: {
      'FORMAT1': 'format1',
      'FORMAT2': 'format2',
      'FORMAT3': 'format3'
    },
    enumerable: true
  },
  FORMAT_LST_COUNT: {
    get: function() {
      return Object.keys(this.FORMAT_LST).length;
    },
    enumerable: true
  }
});

console.log(UTILS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
var UTILS = {
    FORMAT_LST: {
        'FORMAT1': 'format1',
        'FORMAT2': 'format2',
        'FORMAT3': 'format3'
    }
}

UTILS.FORMAT_LST_COUNT = Object.keys(UTILS.FORMAT_LST).length
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign()` in next line.

```js
var UTILS = {
    FORMAT_LST: {
        'FORMAT1': 'format1',
        'FORMAT2': 'format2',
        'FORMAT3': 'format3'
    }
}
Object.assign(UTILS, {
  FORMAT_LST_COUNT: Object.keys(UTILS.FORMAT_LST).length
})
console.log(UTILS);
```